# How to disable all other events in jquery when animation is in progress

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing here againg, because I have some problems with script in my page. I had one problem with menu focus and I write it a week or two ago at this forum, but the awesome script which suggest me one user has one bug and I don't know how to solve it. I have tried a lot's of plausible solutions, but problem still persists.

Here is code at Fiddle, which simulates my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/PRZYN/15/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#handle').mouseenter(slideIn);
    $("#box").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            left: "-=180px"
        }, "fast");
        $('#handle').mouseenter(slideIn);
    });
    $("[name='skin']").mouseleave(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});

function slideIn() {
    if ($("#box")) $("#box").animate({
        left: "+=180px"
    }, "slow");
    $(this).unbind("mouseenter");
}
```

As you can see, there is one div (blue-green one which presents left menu pop-up), which show when div get focus and hide when div lost focus.

Problem in this script is, that when are this two divs in animation state and If user very fast move mouse through animation of front end animation and backend the script gets confused and menu start showing and hiding and it's very annoying. Also there are some other ways when menu gets the same bug but I didn't located it very well. I think, that problem also shows when user hover this div and mouse stop at some place - which is different from time to time.

I have located problem somehow, but I don't know how to solve it. I need to disable all other events on this div (but not .animation()) when menu is in animation state and on elements when mouse is not over div and then enable it again when animation complete and user wants again open or hide menu.

I hope, that you understand my question and I will be very happy if someone could help me on that how to solve problem.

Regards,
Miha

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.stop()` to cancel your animation queue and to prevent the animation from running after the user has stopped interacting with the element. Also, it's better to used fixed values for `left`, as using `+=` and `-=` will cause the box to be incorrectly aligned after rapidly mousing in and out of the container. ie use values such as `"-180px"` and `"0px"` instead of `"-=180px"` and `"+=180px"`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PRZYN/16/

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed!!! This has solved all my problems and animation works pretty well now!! I am happy, that there are still people, who helps you. Thanks again extramaster!